# How to redirect a user after link verification to own customize UI in aws cognito?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

After the signup a link will send to user registered email from cognito to verify the account, When user clicking the link it will redirect to cognito verify UI, but I want to redirect user to my own UI. How to achieve this

I did some research regarding this, I found use pre-signup lambda trigger, or create an API, now I didn't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessary have to use a pre-signup lambda trigger. You can modify what the "Email verification message" says, and include a link to your web page. Here is the window where you configure the email message:

[image: Cognito email verification form]

By default it just send you the code. You can modify it to have a link to your webpage.

Then, you can validate the user using `boto3`, using the [`confirm_sign_up`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.confirm_sign_up) method like this:

```py
response = client.confirm_sign_up(
    ClientId='string',
    SecretHash='string',
    Username='string',
    ConfirmationCode='string',
    ForceAliasCreation=True|False,
    AnalyticsMetadata={
        'AnalyticsEndpointId': 'string'
    },
    UserContextData={
        'EncodedData': 'string'
    }
)
```

The `ConfirmationCode` is the one sent to the user's email, which you have to send along to your request.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to send confirmation code on user email, only link should be send on user email then user click on confirm link and redirect to UI.

Comment: You can't avoid sending the confirmation code. You need it to validate the user. What you do is you pass it as a query parameter inside the redirect url, and you handle it for your user. Something like: http://your.site/confirm?code=<code>

Comment: This answer allowed me to create a very fluid verification system. User signs up and gets an email.I used the instructions [here](https://www.thedevelobear.com/post/styling-cognito-verification-email/) to customize the verification message to include a link to my website with the cognito username and the verification code in the URL , i.e. mydomain.com/verify?username=username123&code=435553. On our API, we grab the code and username, and follow the instructions on this answer to submit a confirmation request via boto. Redirect on success/failure. Works like a charm!

Comment: @TheBrockEllis great solution! Wish I had seen this a few days ago. Works great for me - just struggling with the redirect, but verification code handoff to lambda as you say, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: But how can you get username in verification code type?

Comment: @AbhimanuSharma  got any workaround for  how to get username in verification code type

Comment: No @YogeshwarTanwar

Comment: works like a charm until some rogue goes to sign someone else up, and just hits your verification system with all possible codes.   There's stuff you can do to mitigate this, but at some point you're better off just using the hosted UI & customizing it.